# What is the best way to figure out which drop down menu item should be active?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a page where the user can edit their information. One of the ways for the user to input information is a drop down menu. I have the value already and I need to make that value the active selection on the drop down menu. I know the most straightfoward way of doing with a bunch of if statements:

```
if ($classVal == "Freshman") {
  echo "
  <select name='class'>
    <option selected>Freshman</option>
    <option>Sophomore</option>
    <option>Junior</option>
    <option>Senior</option>
  </select>
  ";
  } else if ($classVal == "Sophomore") {
    echo "
    <select name='class'>
    <option>Freshman</option>
    <option selected>Sophomore</option>
    <option>Junior</option>
    <option>Senior</option>
    </select> </p>
    ";
    } else if ($classVal == "Junior") { ... }
```

This way has worked for me but I was wondering if there was a better way of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can test var inline like this :

```
 echo "
  <select name='class'>
    <option ".($classVal == "Freshman" ? "selected" : "").">Freshman</option>
    <option ".($classVal == "Sophomore" ? "selected" : "").">Sophomore</option>
    <option ".($classVal == "Junior" ? "selected" : "").">Junior</option>
    <option ".($classVal == "Senior" ? "selected" : "").">Senior</option>
  </select>
  ";
```

Comment: One small  >  missing in front of Senior, actually mismoved ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
    $options = array('Freshman','Sophomore','Junior','Senior');
    ?>

    <select name='class'>
    <?php foreach($options as $op):?>
        <option<?php echo $classVal==$op?'selected':'';?>> <?php echo $op;?> </option>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    </select>
```